# Using output to set a variable in a merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I have a merge statement that should update or insert a single record always. I want to remember the ID of that statement in a variable. It looks like this:

```
DECLARE @int int

MERGE dbo.table AS A
USING (SELECT 'stringtomatch' AS string) AS B ON B.string= A.string
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET somecolumn = 'something'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
    VALUES ('stringtomatch',
        'something')
OUTPUT @int = inserted.ID;
```

Now this doesen't work because you can't set @int in the output clause this way. I know I could create a temptable and use **INTO @temptable** in the output. But since I **know** it's always a single record I want to have the ID in a INT variable.
Is this even possible? Or am I forced to use a table variable.

How?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you have to use a table variable with OUTPUT

However, you can do this...

```
...
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET
       @int = ID,
       somecolumn = 'something'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT 
    VALUES ('stringtomatch',
        'something');

SET @int = ISNULL(@int, SCOPE_IDENTITY());
```

The ["assign in UPDATE"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) has been a valid syntax for SQL Server for a long time. See [MERGE on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) too. Both say this:

> ...
> `<set_clause>::=`
>
> SET
> ...
> @variable=expression

Comment: Thx for the straight answer and alternative. Didn't know about the assign in UPDATE, thx allot for the info. Will accept as answer as soon as I can, since your so fast :P

Answer (score 0):

Know this is ten years old but I came across it and thought I would add another answer.  The problem with the selected answer is it's not idempotent.  It will only work for inserts and not updates from what I have seen.  You can use the built in 'OUTPUT' like you were doing. But just bite the bullet and make a table of one column of the type you want and then get a max of that.

```
DECLARE @A Table ( ID INT, VAL CHAR);
DECLARE @B Table ( ID INT, VAL CHAR);
DECLARE @Results TABLE ( ID INT );
DECLARE @Id INT;

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO @A VALUES (1, 'A');

MERGE @B AS T
USING @A AS S ON T.Id = S.Id
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET T.VAL = S.VAL
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (ID, VAL) VALUES (S.ID, S.VAL)
OUTPUT inserted.Id
INTO @Results
;

SELECT @Id = MAX(Id) FROM @Results

SELECT @Id
```