# set a value to a variable in a merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, merge

Thanks NLwino for this question:
[Using output to set a variable in a merge statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838724/using-output-to-set-a-variable-in-a-merge-statement)

I am looking for returning the value of my new counter_ from inside the MERGE:

```
        DECLARE @CounterType VARCHAR(50)
        SET @CounterType = 'Case';

        MERGE [dbo].[AN_Counter] WITH(ROWLOCK) TARGET
        
        USING(SELECT @CounterType) SOURCE([KEY])
        ON TARGET.[System_Name] = SOURCE.[KEY]
        
        WHEN MATCHED THEN

              UPDATE
                 SET COUNTER_ = COALESCE(COUNTER_,0) + 1
                 
              SELECT @CounterType = COALESCE(Prefix,'') + 
                 CAST(SUBSTRING('0000000000000000000000000000',
                                1,
                                padding - LEN(CAST (Counter_ AS VARCHAR ))) 
                 + CAST (Counter_ AS VARCHAR ) AS VARCHAR);
```

I would like to execute the merge, and put the new value inside the @CounterType variable, as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done, I would like to share here how i did it:

```
SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[AN_Counter]   WHERE System_Name = 'Case'   

DECLARE @CounterType VARCHAR(50)
SET @CounterType = 'Case'  

DECLARE @RADHE TABLE (
[Counter_] [int] NULL,
[Prefix] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Padding] [int] NULL
)

BEGIN TRANSACTION TR_ORDER_NUMBERS


INSERT INTO @RADHE( 
                 [Counter_]
                ,[Prefix]
                ,[Padding]
               )

SELECT  
                 [Counter_]
                ,[Prefix]
                ,[Padding]
FROM                  
(
        MERGE [dbo].[AN_Counter] WITH(ROWLOCK) TARGET

        USING(SELECT @CounterType) SOURCE([KEY])
        ON TARGET.[System_Name] = SOURCE.[KEY]

        WHEN MATCHED THEN

              UPDATE
                 SET COUNTER_ = COALESCE(COUNTER_,0) + 1

        OUTPUT $Action AS The_Action
               ,INSERTED.Counter_ 
               ,INSERTED.Prefix   
               ,INSERTED.Padding  
) Outputs
WHERE The_Action = 'UPDATE';

SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[AN_Counter] 
     WHERE System_Name = 'Case' 

SELECT * FROM @RADHE

SELECT COALESCE(R.Prefix,'') + CAST(SUBSTRING('0000000000000000000000000000',1,R.Padding - LEN(CAST (R.Counter_ AS VARCHAR ))) + CAST (R.Counter_ AS VARCHAR ) AS VARCHAR)
FROM @RADHE R


SELECT XACT_STATE()
```